# How to revamp a website from wordpress to wix without changing the domain & without losing the mailbox linked with that domain?

Tags: wordpress, host, velo

I want to change a website from wordpress to wix. The challenge is that- If I connected the existing domain directly to wix, will I lose my mailbox?

Please suggest how to connect mailbox to wix without losing it?

Comment: Do you mean that you will lose the emails you already received? Because you [can have email address on your domain](https://www.wix.com/business/email-address) and [you can use G suite as client](https://www.wix.com/blog/2020/11/how-to-create-a-business-email/#:~:text=04.%20access%20your%20personalized%20mailbox).

Comment: If I connect my mailbox with WIX, will there be any loss of data or will I be using it the same way I used it before?

Comment: I believe you will lose the emails sent before moving to wix.

Comment: So there is no way to save previous emails & move to wix?

Comment: In theory you can have 2 different providers for email and website. I don't know who's your email provider but maybe you can keep it and point the DNS record to wix only for the website.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a strange question.

Wix is indeed a SaaS, providing hosting, a domain, ... which means that in order to use Wix, you either develop your platform within their SaaS environment OR you use their SaaS environment to provide services to an external platform.

I see only one option to adhere to the requirements you shared. If you want to keep the current host, but you want to use Wix, you'll have to provide services from Wix to your external website.

For the moment, this sounds more like an architectural question, so you might want to be more explicit.

Comment: My website was build using wordpress. Domain from Google LLC and hosted on hostgator.

But it didn't turn out that good so now I want to build a new website using wix, using same domain name and also don't want to lose my mailbox.

Can you please suggest how to do that?

Comment: @user16178900 you can transfer your domain, but you can't transfer an existing email account or mailbox to Wix. See: https://support.wix.com/en/article/transferring-a-domain-purchased-elsewhere-to-wix and https://support.wix.com/en/article/request-transferring-your-existing-email-to-wix

Comment: So if I connect my mailbox with WIX, will there be any loss of data or will I be using it the same way I used it before?

Comment: @user16178900 I'd advice to keep your mailbox as-is. Maybe you can scale down your current hosting packet to e-mail only to limit costs?

Comment: But if I have to necessarily connect the mailbox to WIX, then will there be any data loss?

Comment: @user16178900 you'll have to get in touch with Wix support on these details. The link I shared earlier was very clear that you cannot transfer an existing email account or mailbox to Wix. This should answer your question. Further questions you have are out of scope of StackOverflow I'm afraid. The previous one as well actually, but thought to help you out anyways.